# Why java Arrays.binarySearch returns strange result?

Tags: java

In standard Java 11 library if element is not found, method should return:

> ...the index of the first
>        element greater than the key...

on Java 11 this sample prints 17

```
int[] data = new int[] {2, 4, 5, 12, 17, 19};
System.out.println(data[-1 *Arrays.binarySearch(data, 6)]);
```

In this code sample, first element greater than 6 is 12, but it returns index of 17. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[binarySearch​(int[] a, int key) :](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int%5B%5D,int))** If the element is not present it returns the index of `(-(insertion point)-1)`. So in the above case insertion point is `3` and the expression is evaluated to `-4`

```
(-(3)-1) --> (-3-1) --> -4
```

And the array with corresponding value at index 4 is 17

```
Array --> {2, 4, 5, 12, 17, 19}
indexes -->0  1  2  3   4    5
```

> index of the search key, if it is contained in the array; **otherwise, (-(insertion point) - 1). The insertion point is defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the array: the index of the first element greater than the key**, or a.length if all elements in the array are less than the specified key. Note that this guarantees that the return value will be >= 0 if and only if the key is found.

Comment: I have read this but actual returning value is not relevant to this

Comment: I don't understand where you are getting confused @tengreencolors, it is returning as mentioned in documentation

Comment: @tengreencolors The return value you're seeing is *exactly* described by this.  6 is not in the array.  It's insertion point would be 3, so `Arrays.binarySearch(data, 6)]` returns `-insertion_point - 1`, which is `-3 - 1` which is `-4`.

Comment: @Deadpool My bad, I did not read doc carefully and after your explanation with actual values I finally got it, thanks.